# How to convert double to minutes in VB

Tags: vb.net

I am currently storing a value as a double but will need to have the value converted to minutes for another function.

For example 1 would convert to 60 (minutes), 3,5 would equal to 210.

I tried timespan but I'm not getting what I am looking for.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`TimeSpan.TotalMinutes`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timespan.totalminutes) should give you what you're looking for:

```
Dim minutes = TimeSpan.FromHours(hours).TotalMinutes
```